# Using importxml to parse data from investing.com

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I am trying to use the importxml to get the percentage changes data from https://www.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin.

[image]

Unfortunately, when I retrieve it with the following formula, it retrieves other data as well.

```
=importxml("https://www.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin","//span[@dir='ltr']",)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the "percentage change" element from a website using `IMPORTXML`. You are using XPath of `//span[@dir='ltr']` but getting a number of values, including  the individual element required.

When extracting the XPath, you need to drill down further into the HTML to identify the specific line for the element that you require. Use the "Developer Tools" provided by your browser (Chrome, Firefox and Edge each have the same set of tools), select the specific line, right click, Copy, Copy XPath.

- XPath for "percentage change": `//*[@id="fullColumn"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[4]`

[image: xtml]

---

**Summary**

[image: summary]